# Load a nuget package installed by Install-Package in Powershell v5.0+

Tags: powershell, .net, powershell-v5.0, .net-4.5

In Powershell v5.1... If I install a .NET NuGet package (example: [`redmine-api`](https://github.com/zapadi/redmine-net-api)) using this command:

```
Install-Package redmine-api
```

How do I then create a new object from that package for use in Powershell?

I've tried:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Redmine.Net.Api
# OUTPUT: Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'Redmine.Net.Api' could not be found.

[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Redmine.Net.Api")
# OUTPUT: (no ouput)

$rdm = New-Object Redmine.Net.Api
# OUTPUT: New-Object : Cannot find type [Redmine.Net.Api]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

Comment: It sounds like Redmind.Net.Api is the assembly name/namespace.  That's not an object in itself.  I don't know anything about that library/namespace, but you'll need to specify an object type.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks for your input. I'll update with an actual answer soon, or feel free to do so yourself if you want the credits!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Matthew, it wasn't working as I was trying to load the namespace into the object. The correct method is:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Redmine.Net.Api")
$rdm = New-Object Redmine.Net.Api.RedmineManager
```

Looking at the package's [docs](https://github.com/zapadi/redmine-net-api/wiki/Create-a-redmine-object), the Assembly name relates to `using Redmine.Net.Api` and the object name relates to `new RedmineManager(host, apiKey)` in C# source code.

Comment: Forgot to post an answer, you can claim it. Glad you solved it. You can upvote the comment, though.